# How to group or sum with the same id in object array

Tags: php

I have this object array. I print this using print_r. I want to sum all the x, y and total with the same id, or group them by id and sum the x,y and total.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[13]
      public 'id' => string '24' (length=2)
      public 'x' => float 2
      public 'y' => float 5
      public 'total' => int 7
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'id' => string '25' (length=2)
      public 'x' => int 0
      public 'y' => float 2
      public 'total' => int 2
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[19]
      public 'id' => string '25' (length=2)
      public 'x' => float 13
      public 'y' => int 0
      public 'total' => int 13
```

Here is my attemp but not working.

```
$sumArray = array();

            foreach ($r as $k=>$subArray) {
                foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {
                    $sumArray = $subArray->x+=$value;
                }
            }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data you have was called `$inputData` this code should create a new array with the items grouped and totaled by ID.

**Update**

Added array_values() to reset the keys.

```
<?php
    $arrayResult = array();
    foreach($inputData as $someInput){
        if(!isset($arrayResult[$someInput->id])){
            $current = new stdClass();
            $current->id = $someInput->id;
            $current->x = $someInput->x;
            $current->y = $someInput->y;
            $current->total = $someInput->total;
            $arrayResult[$someInput->id] = $current;
        }else{
            $current = $arrayResult[$someInput->id];
            $current->x += $someInput->x;
            $current->y += $someInput->y;
            $current->total += $someInput->total;
            $arrayResult[$someInput->id] = $current;
        }
    }
    $arrayResult = array_values($arrayResult);
?>
```

Comment: @jemz That is more or less what this generates. I am confused where 'inrange' and 'outrange' came from but the only difference is they are 'x and 'y' respectively in my code.

Comment: I have some problem, I cannot display this to my tables, I need to format like this    [{"id":"24","x":2,"y":5,"total":7},{"id":"25","x":13,"y":2,"total":15}] , but if change your code like this in the last part $arrayResult[] = $current; , I can display but the id's are repetead, If I put it back $arrayResult[$someInput->id] = $current; works fine the output is correct but I cannot display to my datables because the format is wrong

Comment: Sorry, the id in the key is what groups them but no worries there is a fix. I will update the code for you now.